# Может ли телеграм бот получить значение количества репостов его записи?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Я делаю телеграм бота- он рассылает пользователям информацию. Назовём её секретной информацией. Но нечестный пользователь взял и сделал сотню репостов секретной записи своим друзьям.
Рядом с постом есть количество просмотров. Соответственно, если человек репостнул и секретную информацию просмотрел не один он, то надо принять меры к этому человеку.
Вопрос- как по api узнать количество просмотров определённого поста?

Answer (score 2):

Количество просмотров сообщения в телеграме отображается только у сообщений, публикуемых в каналах, у всех остальных сообщений такой фичи нет. В API все сообщения - публикуемые в каналах, группах или приватных чатах - имеют один и тот же тип, тип [Message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message). Работа со счётчиком просмотров этого объекта через API **пока не доступна**.

Comment: но сам телеграм в каналах эту информацию выдаёт. Значит, подключившись по api к каналу- можно получать эту информацию? или разработчики скрывают это? просто код телеграма открытый, но я в c++ не разбираюсь((

Comment: @RakzinRoman, что именно в словах *Работа со счётчиком просмотров этого объекта через API пока не доступна* Вам не понятно?

Comment: Код-то открытый, но это никакого отношения к апи не имеет